# Parse : Trying multiple query in a function of Parse Cloud code. Second query doesn't seem to work

Tags: parse-platform

I am trying to run multiple queries inside Parse cloud function. Second query doesnt get
executed

Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("PhoneNumbers", function(request, response) {

```
// Check if the same phone number for the same user exists
var PhoneNumbersObject = Parse.Object.extend('PhoneNumbers');

var duplicationQuery = new Parse.Query(PhoneNumbersObject);
duplicationQuery.equalTo('user', Parse.User.current());
duplicationQuery.equalTo('phoneNumber', request.object.get("phoneNumber"));

duplicationQuery.count({
    success: function(count) {
        if (count > 0) {
            response.error("This number is already stored");
        }
    },
    error: function(error) {
        response.error("Error " + error.code + " : " + error.message + " when storing phone number");
    }
});

var firstPhoneNumberQuery = new Parse.Query(PhoneNumbersObject);
firstPhoneNumberQuery.equalTo('user', Parse.User.current());

firstPhoneNumberQuery.find({                           //  <<<<< find doesn't work
    success: function(results) {
        if ( results.length == 0 ) {
            console.log("User's first telephone number");     // <<< Never reaches here
            request.object.set("primary", true);
        } else {
            console.log("Hello");                      // <<< Never reaches here
        }
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log("Bye");
        response.error("Query failed. Error = " + error.message);
    }
});

response.success();
```

});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that queries are async. You're not waiting for the query to finish before calling `response.success()`.

Think of your call to `firstPhoneNumberQuery.find()` like putting eggs on to boil, the `success` and `error` blocks are what you'll do when it is done.

The call to `response.success()` is like telling the cleaners you are done and they can toss whatever is still "cooking".

Use promises to avoid this issue, as well as moving the `response.success()` call inside your query's `success` handler:

```
duplicationQuery.count({
    // ... success / error as above
}).then(function() {
    var firstPhoneNumberQuery = new Parse.Query(PhoneNumbersObject);
    firstPhoneNumberQuery.equalTo('user', Parse.User.current());
    // return the promise so we can keep chaining
    return firstPhoneNumberQuery.find();
}).then(function(results) {
    // ... success for find
    // then call success() here
    response.success();
}, function(error) {
    // ... error block for find
});
```

As you can see, you can combine as many `then()` blocks as you need.

Learn more about promises and chaining here:

https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#promises